# Is this proof of contrapositive correct? (Number Theory)/(Proof Theory)

Tags: number-theory

By using the contrapositive implication, prove that, **IF**

$$ a^2(b^2 -2b)$$ is odd then, a and b are odd where a, b ∈ ℤ

---

*Suppose a odd and b is even*

Show that $$a^2 (b^2 – 2b) = 2k$$ 
$$(2k + 1)^2 [(2k)^2 – 2(2k)]$$ 
$$(4k^2 + 4k + 1) (4k^2 – 4k)$$
$$(4k^2 + 4k + 1)[(2)(2k^2) – 2k)]$$

Therefore it fits the form where *2k* 
$$(2(2k^2 – 2k))$$ ∈ ℤ

Thus $$a^2 (b^2 – 2b)$$ is even

Comment: The opposite of "$a$ and $b$ are odd" is "$a$ *or* $b$ is even".

Comment: The inverse of "$a$ and $b$ is odd" is "at least one of $a$ and $b$ is even". Can you understand the difference between "at least one of $a$ and $b$ is even" and "$a$ and $b$ is even"?

Comment: okay got you. So I would put k + 1 for one of them while the other has 2k.

Comment: I updated. Would it be correct now?

Comment: No, a or b is even does not mean a is odd and b is even.

Comment: a is odd and b is even. That's what I did.